Can I run the microsoft compiler cl in the terminal on linux?
Following this method :
https://linuxiac.com/how-to-install-vs-code-on-linux-mint/
I've just installed VSCODE on linuxmint.
On windows I can run the compiler on the command line simply typing: cl
Is there a way to do this on linux too ?
Edit: I've installed the C/C++ extension, but it seems that microsoft didn't actually port its compiler to linux, just its IDE. Thus it is using gcc and not cl.

That's right. Microsoft C/C++ compiler (cl.exe) exists for Windows only. It is not and never was part of VS Code or Microsoft C++ extension for VS Code, it is completely separate thing. On Linux, the "standard" C++ compiler is GCC. So you'll typically will want to use exactly it. You can also install clang.

VS Code has great support for developing inside a container.
I found this project which allows you to create a container image which will run MSVC 2022 on Wine.  You will need a Windows PC to build the image, but you will then be able to run the image on Linux.  This method will allow you to run cl on Linux in your VS Code command line.
